# Stripe – refund from connected account, without charging the account

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a connected stripe account. Example transaction looks like this:

- **Charged to a customer:** 69.00PLN
- **Application fee:** 10.35PLN
- **Stripe's processing fee:** 2.31PLN
- **Profit for the connected account:** 56.34PLN

The customer agreed that if applicable, the service can be refunded, but the amount that was paid (here 69.00PLN) will be reduced by Stripe's processing fee – we do not want the Connected Account to pay for it.

When I issue a refund from within the connected account dashboard, it looks like this (the amount entered is `69.00 - 2.31 = 66.69`):
[image]

After the refund is processed, the net value for the connected account looks like this:
[image]

**Question:**
Is it possible to refund the value reduced by Stripe's processing fee, without touching the application fee? I just want to fully refund the `application fee` + `profit for the connected account`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is to first refund the fee (here 10.35PLN) from the main Stripe account and then refund the rest (66.69PLN) from the connected account.